# When will an instance of a controller be created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm learning Ruby on Rails currently and I'm wondering when an instance of a controller class is created. An instance for each action request? Or one instance that is shared between one client's requests?

I can see there are instance variables in the controller class and they are shared with the view, so I think that a controller instance is created on each action request. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, each http request from a client will create a new controller instance and call that action method on it. The controller instance variables will be accessible to the view

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: @house9, I think you should add that as an answer instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, each http request from a client will create a new controller instance and call that action method on it. The controller instance variables will be accessible to the view.

Check rails guides for more detail: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html